# Type key when iterating an object

Tags: typescript, for-loop, object, key

I have this function that adjusts the initial state of a React component based on an API response.

```
export const getInitialStateByData = (initialData: TApiResponseData, fields: TFormFields) => {
  for (const [key] of Object.entries(initialData)) {
    if (!fields.includes(key)) {
      delete initialData[key]
    }
  }

  return initialData
}
```

I am facing this error `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TLocaleKey'.ts(2345) const key: string`

I have tried `for (const [key]: [TLocaleKey] of Object.entries(initialData)) ...`
with `The left-hand side of a 'for...of' statement cannot use a type annotation.` error.

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkDsEsBdoIYBtQGdYNgU1AIwJ6gCCACuKAE5aoAOA9pKlgFBYAe9FsoAxg+qADmWWFDiIkAZQzYAQvgAimBKAC8oABTQY8ZEowAuUABUiNaACVq9Rln0IANKABm0LEgAmqI8YBidCgBbXzdPVABKNQA+UABvZlAXAM0+Rm4AbQBrLHwAXSN04wAZOh5kLABpHNzQOmdQAHlcACssHlgAOixIWAo3VC0dCXtwyPjExOh6jQBCV3cvDu0eJABXD2oNbPxRuISJxI2kERxtcT1lLOr9xIBfffv9qlhVikhQM90ke2ZH1g4AtxYPgaDhTOYrLR+HZlGpQCQEFwJAAeKx8CgeZHFUrlKr4JzoPqQQRRKL-ThAkFg-xBEILVBw7FlY549K5ZjkwGgYGgkwlZmVHKMgBqbgA7vzcUKAD4mACiFAoAUlLJloAA5AgPB4qKhUOrQLLNYEALJYQK4LAUA1G3DQJBIbSCIja3X6w0asqQHjuSSrXCoHh9GjwBg2z2IjwAOVWFqt4fVPAAFghoEEEJAE0GsB44O6jR5MFgE4XsA1nLI07AkyWRKmkLWMPb8xrzfWE+xzLqE0noBsaYEE9A9ascwmkHRBMIPFBx5PtKKsGK5-hkMCAMKRldr-BFLAAN3cCcgCECxY96sgdGPdBIr2TCCYqAAmiIb8K6Ktk1aX2+L3USlXJBgRIJVBAoU8ExoR9UDFDwoJ-Bg9DrZsoKTBhzyNehtFgVBZGQDMfSgvp9wQHh8CIcCsDHC8aBIsiKKonNAJ3KDAwTVBkFWGRoAYE1rQvTi1h4viKBbdUmEgDwrAAR03b13DNOMxN7GgOPYDj0LUwT0OXQTemo2AOIMkQY2Ujj-UDPpLQswdBNeE8zwTeBYGOZy4GOAAmdzXKwKNT0wjVYDoMVMwvUi1kC9V90-b8xKIUj7QQXA3PC2Kkx-KM6FgBL62S1KjTFdw+Cci98GoBN8E-CgSDoHC8IIhTwH1TkuG5KkTEXCUcVVQh1ETFNiTsFCkHEidBG0bdgPwD8vwysSE0CCieD4VYeig+8UyYEpBHVVrKV5YwFSVCgVUFPqNTlQJh1QBE9TghMrpu-zSqNJ69T9N4Ase66PpMoyL3e1BpCoUzY0tAS3t+1BjBCsKoZukh2MB6GSHQyAoqBq720B1B0K4O7YPg3H8dgYwPMxvHAXJ3zvJJwEXsp0nPscpnARBwzHqprgObB8z6a4WHQq50mkZ4EXATRjCJa4bH7UeidiUJh7AcVwQaYKy61Y1rA6betXGYVhhBBZ77VeN3mAf1i3-rMiGjeJIX4a142xYdwQpYx925YbQGr1ESBJA0v3srNWArGENhleJt7-bDiP2B1x645EBO2B1vXLpT8OsEjw2Q9gePc-YU3Xqz0PU+Lth9CwctKy4GsC6LyPLeTiuc5b23wfjJvK8jp228Lvv2Dd3uO5H9HMeztOfb2oA)

Any solution to type the key? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error mentions a parameter of type `TLocaleKey` but your code example doesn't show a function with a parameter that has that type.  Can you double check you've shared the relevant code? Also add a comment to which line is causing the error. Please also include any relevant types. Even better would be sharing code in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) so folks can interact with it easily.

Comment: @Wing Thanks for heading me up. I have added a link to the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for `Object.entries` is as follows (this is why `key` is typed as `string`):

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    ...

    /**
     * Returns an array of key/values of the enumerable properties of an object
     * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
     */
    entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];

    /**
     * Returns an array of key/values of the enumerable properties of an object
     * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
     */
    entries(o: {}): [string, any][];

    ...
}
```

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0d022130be83fbcf8be26b7181c18469f3a613b6/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L34-L44)

As a result, we won't be able to leverage the type parameter; the first item in the tuple `entries` returns will always be of type `string`. An aside: if you're curious, [this is why](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208).

There isn't a way to cast the variable declared in the for loop (as far as I know). As a result you'll have to cast the array:

```
for (const [key] of (Object.entries(initialData) as [TLocaleKey, string][])) { ... }
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkDsEsBdoIYBtQGdYNgU1AIwJ6gCCACuKAE5aoAOA9pKlgFBYAe9FsoAxg+qADmWWFDiIkAZQzYAQvgAimBKAC8oABTQY8ZEowAuUABUiNaACVq9Rln0IANKABm0LEgAmqI8YBidCgBbXzdPVABKNQA+UABvZlAXAM0+Rm4AbQBrLHwAXVA6Z00AeVwAKyweWAA6LEhYCjdULR0Je0iEVFB04wAZOh5kLABpHKd0RshBXPTc8Mj4xMToIo0AQld3L2rtHiQAVw9qDWz8ebiEpcSjpBEcbXE9ZSyc3MvEgF9Lr8uqWH2KJBQA9dEh7MwfqwOAFuLB8DQcKZzFZaPw7Mo1KASAguBIADxWPgUDx4voDIajfDjBraQRRKJQziw+GI-xBEJbLrqMmDW6U2bMRkw0BwhEmfq8kY5THGABqbgA7hKKdKAD4mACiFAoAWVfLVoAA5AgPB4qKhUIbQOrjYEALJYQK4LAUK023DQJBIWlEU3my3Wo2DSA8dySfa4VA8Ro0eAMN1BnEeABy+ydLoThp4AAsENAgghIJno1gPHAAzaPJgsJmq9his5ZPnYNnayI80g2xhPRWjY6O5n2OZzZns9AjmzApnoBb9qXM0g6IJhB4oAul9p5VgFev8Mg4QBhJO7-f4XpYABu7kzkAQgRrgcNkDoN7oJABOc61AAmiJX7K6H2HMXVQX9YEzQp+j3JA4RIHVBAoO9MxoTpUAVDxkJAhg9HbHtkOzBgHxtehtFgVBZGQQtQ2QxoLwQHh8CIBCsHnR8aFo+jGOY0soNPZCo0zVBkH2GRoAYO1XUfISDlE8SKF7Q0mEgDwrAARyPEN3AddN5LHGhBPYQSCP0qSCJ3KSGhY8CLKoERUx0wSIyjRpnUcqcpIBW970zeBYFuHy4FuAAmAK-KwZM7yIo1YDoBUi0fOiDiiw0L0A4D5KIOjPQQXB-IStLsxA5M6FgTKOxyvKbQVdw+G8x98GoTN8EAigSDoUjyMozTwEtIUuBFFkTC3JVyX1Qh1CzXMpjsXCkAUxdBG0E8YPwACgMK+TM0CRieD4fZ6mQj9cyYfpBENPrmTFYwtR1Cg9SlcajQ1QIZ1QbELXQzNnteiK6ptb6LXDQFIq+l7Acsv9HwB1BpFs2B7OdST-rB1BjFi+LkdekgBKhlGSAIyBkuh56Byh1ACK4d60IwsmKdgYxAqJ8mYQZsKQtpmFfqZumga87mYVhqyvuZrhBbstNEeFum0biqWYWxng5cpgn+a4EnPS+xcpipz6oa1wRWcqp79cNrB2f+-Wuc1hhBF5kG9ZtsXrItx2IfhiWMwdqYZYx42bYV63tZVwPBHVzsoefURIEkQyI5Kh1YCsYQ2B1mn-sjhOk-YU2vozkQs7YU3zaevPE6wZOrbj2BM-L9g7b+kv4-z2u2H0LAGybLhWyrmvk6d3Om7Lvu3YRz308HgufYH6vm+TgOe9n9h8cI6fe-YMPzqAA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanatory reply with references.